# Downtempo song, where a female voice says “Don't stop”

Tags: identify-this-song, electronic-music

The song is very relaxed and I am reasonably confident that it features smooth-sounding (closer to sine wave than to the saw wave) synthesizers. I recreated the main theme [here](https://soundcloud.com/witiko/mystery-track/s-mnxWn). I recall the main theme follows immediately after the female voice.

With regards to the helpful tips from [“What should I do to improve my identification question?”](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/a/368/5997) suggested by Bebs:

- I attempted to search for the the lyrics “Don't stop” at [Lyrics Wikia](http://lyrics.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Search?query=don%27t+stop), [Metrolyrics](http://www.metrolyrics.com/search.html?search=don%27t+stop), [Lyrics Mania](https://www.lyricsmania.com/search.php?k=don%27t+stop&x=0&y=0), and [Find Music By Lyrics](https://findmusicbylyrics.com/search?q=don%27t+stop) with no success. Admittedly, a single soundbite makes for a poor query.
- The song was used as a background track in a YouTube video I listened to around 2010. The year of production is unknown to me, although this one may become clearer if we pin down the genre.

Comment: what does Shazam or SoundHound make of your recreation of the main theme ?

Comment: Neither finds any close matches.

Comment: Do you know this group ? 
The Identification of Music Group:
https://www.facebook.com/groups/1165001636849150/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be thinking of "Don't Stop" by ATB, with it's very distinctive sliding notes sound.

[youtube ATB Don't Stop official video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgvePeDIt3Y)